# The expression contained an invalid collating element name

Tags: c++14

My reg object created with below expression:

```
std::string regE("\\s*[0-9A-Za-z_.]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9._()\\s-,/*+!~\"'?<>\\[\\]{}|^%$#@]+");
std::regex r(regE);
```

and i am getting below exception at runtime:

The expression contained an invalid collating element name

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__1::regex_error'
  what():  The expression contained an invalid collating element name.

Comment: I understand that collating element name indicating below expression as per ECMA script:       [.classname.] collating sequence Uses the regex traits' lookup_collatename to interpret classname.                                                             
 But i didn't exactly know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The error originates from this place:

```
\\s*[0-9A-Za-z_.]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9._()\\s-,/*+!~\"'?<>\\[\\]{}|^%$#@]+
                                           ~^~
```

The dash character, `-`, gains a special meaning inside a bracket expression, i.e., it specifies a range of characters. Because there's no such range as `[\\s-,]`, that is, starting from `\s` and ending with `,`, an error is reported.

In order to parse `-` literally, it must be at the beginning of the character sequence enclosed by brackets (excluding the `^` negation operator), at the end, or escaped with `\`.

Also notice that C++ supports raw string literals, that can be used to avoid escaping characters and thus make regular expressions more readable. Having said that, the correct and simplified regular expression could be:

```
std::regex r(R"(\s*[0-9A-Za-z_.]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9._()\s\-,/*+!~"'?<>\[\]{}|^%$#@]+)");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Piotr. sorry for the delay response :)

Yes you are almost right ....

Answer (score 0):

In my expression i have done 2 mistakes:

1)     \s*[0-9A-Za-z_.]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9._()\s-

```
 the last '-'  Character range is out of order
```

2)     /*+!~\"'?<>\[\]{}|^%$#@]+

```
 the first '/' character is an unescaped delimiter so it must be escaped with a backslash (\)
```

Comment: and final expression is:

    std::string regE("\\s*[0-9A-Za-z_.]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9._()\\s\\-,\\/*+!~\"'?<>\\[\\]{}|^%$#@]+");    
    std::regex r(regE);